# Selecting a specific string array

Tags: android

I have a question and i cant find a solution myself. I am using for example the following string arrays:

```
     <string-array name="alphabet">
     <item>ccc</item>
     <item>bbb</item>
     <item>aaa</item>
     </string-array>



     <string-array name="ccc">
     <item>1</item>
     <item>2</item>
     <item>3</item>
     </string-array>


     <string-array name="bbb">
     <item>4</item>
     <item>5</item>
     <item>6</item>
     </string-array>


     <string-array name="aaa">
     <item>7</item>
     <item>8</item>
     <item>9</item>
     </string-array>
```

So, The first string array alphabet is placed inside a spinner. (dropdown menu) Lets say i select CCC, Then i want only the items in between the array CCC to be worked with and stored in an array These information in this array should then be randomized and formatted into groups later on. But i only need a selection of the string selected.

So is there a way to select just one array based on the choice made out of the first array?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, the way you needed.

Step 1] Set, setOnItemSelectedListener on first spinner and get the Arrayname for target spinner

```
spinner_alphabates.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
        {

            String arrayName = spinner_alphabates.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayName,"array",getPackageName());

            setResultArray(resId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Step 2] set the result array on target spinner as

```
public void setResultArray(int resID)
{
    String [] result_array = getResources().getStringArray(resID);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, result_array);
    spinner_result.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

No need to put 'if' 'else' conditions to match array names.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure whether it is going to work, just have try

```
<string-array name="ccc">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>

<integer-array name="id">
    <item> @array/ccc </item>
</integer-array>
```

Comment: Hello sir, Im quite sure it wont work. The problem is i am using a spinner(dropdown) and i want my script to read out which item is selected and then use the  array that has the same name.

Comment: I would prefer you to use JSON object store somewhere and parse it

{
  "aaa": [
    {
      "0": "0",
      "1": "1",
      "2": "2"
    }
  ],
  "bbb": [
    {
      "3": "3",
      "4": "4",
      "5": "5"
    }
  ],
  "ccc": [
    {
      "6": "6",
      "7": "7",
      "8": "8"
    }
  ]
}

It would be more convinient

Answer (score 0):

You need to get array of string like this. and you will access it with index of string array.

**String.xml**

```
<string-array name="my_books">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
    <item>Item 4</item>
</string-array>
```

**Get List of string in Java file like :**

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] myBooks = res.getStringArray(R.array.my_books);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method and put this method into onCreate in activity method..

change this array add one more item..

```
<string-array name="alphabet">

    <item>Select</item>
    <item>ccc</item>
    <item>bbb</item>
    <item>aaa</item>
</string-array>

private void initView() {
     spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.alphabet));
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, asList);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("ccc")) {
                adapter2.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ccc)));
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("aaa")) {
                adapter2.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aaa)));
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals("bbb")) {
                adapter2.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bbb)));
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
```